# Эстоно- или эстонско-

Tags: суффиксация

Кто знает точно? Эстоно-американские отношения или эстонско-американские? Испано-американские или испанско-американские? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отношения между странами - эстоно- и испано-, от стран Эстония, Испания.

В отличие, например, от словарей: испанско-русский словарь, от "испанский", а не Испания.

Японо-китайская война, но японско-китайский разговорник.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому возможны и японско-российское предприятие и японо-российское (межстрановое и межнациональное). Но: японо-российские внешнеторговые и экономические отношения.

Answer (score 3):

Интереснейший вопрос. Безусловно, "эстонско-русский словарь" (суффикс - от прилагательного "эстонский" /язык/, которого в других случаях словообразования не находится в слове "эстония"), но...

Крайне непривычно русскому слуху "эстоно-" (по аналогии с обычным "японо-") - просто из-за долговременного отсутствия составных понятий, образованных от названия сравнительно новой страны; об эстоно-российской границе раньше не говорили, а международные отношения нынешней Эстонии и сейчас редко обсуждаются публично и т.п. В эстонском русскоязычном интернете с "эстоно-" нет проблем, в русском же чаще встречается вариант "эстонско-". По отношению к "эстонско-русской границе" условно можно допустить связь с прилагательным (отчасти это "эстонская граница с Россией", отчасти - российская с Эстонией). Но на отношения Эстонии с Америкой прилагательное не перенести: такие отношения заключаются во взаимодействии, а не в сложении "эстонского отношения" к Америке и "американского" к Эстонии. Поэтому *правильным* для данного случая следует признать вариант "**эстоно-**", с единственным, общим суффиксом прилагательного. Если, конечно, циркулярно не будет зафиксировано исключение из правил.

Answer (score 1):

> Эстоно-американские отношения или эстонско-американские?
>   Испано-американские или испанско-американские?

**Правильны все эти варианты.** Можно говорить лишь о большей или меньшей их предпочтительности в настоящее время.

В сложениях с основами относительных отсубстантивных прилагательных, где опорным компонентом  является суффиксальное прилагательное, **предшествующая основа может быть как суффиксальной, так и бессуффиксальной.**

В тех случаях, когда возможен выбор, **чаще** используется    более экономный вариант.

Ср.:  ***[испано-американские отношения](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%22%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=raFYVtroCoqtsgHw8Dw#newwindow=1&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22)  --  [испанско-американские отношения](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%22%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=raFYVtroCoqtsgHw8Dw#newwindow=1&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22).***

Предпочтительны по сравнению с суффиксальными бессуффиксальные  варианты ***испано-, японо-, англо-, австро...***  Но не ***эстоно.*** Эта форма всё же употребляется значительно реже, чем ***эстонско.***

Ср.: ***[эстоно-российские отношения](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=PcxYVrGxAqf5ywON-bxg#q=%22%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&newwindow=1&nfpr=1&tbm=bks) --  [эстонско-российские отношения](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=PcxYVrGxAqf5ywON-bxg#newwindow=1&tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22).***

Comment: Характерно, что с российской стороны термин "эстон(ск)о-российские отношения" не используется - за полной его ненадобностью: это всегда "российско-эстонские отношения". А эстонцы уверенно пишут "эстоно-" (правда, в сочетании с "-российскими" слово почти не встречается).

Comment: Как пишут эстонцы -- это их дело. В российских же публикациях **"эстонско-"** используется несравненно чаще, чем **"эстоно-".** Пусть не "эстон...-российские", пусть какие-либо другие отношения... В каких из _отношений_ в русских изданиях Вы сможете найти преимущественное употребление "эстоно"? Думаю, ни в каких.

Comment: Пример источника, проходившего корректуру: из научно-практического краеведческого журнала "Псков", №22, 2005 (серьёзная статья с 76 источниками в библиографии), "эстоно-латвийский" встречается 13 раз. http://izd.pskgu.ru/projects/pgu/storage/PSKOV/ps22/ps_22_18.pdf